# I have very long equation in latex. How should I divide it into multiple line?

Tags: math-mode, align, line-breaking

```
\begin{align}
\left[\frac{-2 b^2 s^2 \log \left(\frac{b \left(a+s^2\right)}{a}\right)-2 a b^2 \log \left(\frac{b \left(a+s^2\right)}{a}\right)
+2 b^2 s^2 \log \left(a+s^2\right)+2 a b^2 \log \left(a+s^2\right)
+2 b s^2 e^{\frac{b \left(a+s^2\right)}{a}} \text{Ei}\left(-\frac{b \left(s^2+a\right)}{a}\right)+2 b s^2 e^{\frac{b \left(a+s^2\right)}{a}} \log \left(\frac{b \left(a+s^2\right)}{a}\right)-2 b s^2 \log \left(\frac{b \left(a+s^2\right)}{a}\right)-2 a b \log \left(\frac{b \left(a+s^2\right)}{a}\right)-b s^2 e^{\frac{b \left(a+s^2\right)}{a}} \log \left(-\frac{b \left(a+s^2\right)}{a}\right)-2 (b+1) b \left(a+s^2\right) \log \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)+2 b s^2 \log \left(a+s^2\right)+2 a b \log \left(a+s^2\right)+b s^2 e^{\frac{b \left(a+s^2\right)}{a}} \log \left(-\frac{a}{b \left(a+s^2\right)}\right)+2 a}{2 a p},\Re\left(a+s^2\right)>0\land \left(\left(\Re\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)\geq 0\land \frac{b}{a}\neq 0\right)\lor \frac{b}{a}\notin \mathbb{R}\right)\right]
\end{align}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Start by removing the `$`. As `align` starts math mode on its own, you don't need/want those.

Comment: Even after removing the outer pair of `$` symbols, the code doesn't compile. Please fix any and all errors, so that readers of your posting will have a better shot at figuring out where to insert line breaks.

Comment: in the third line, \frac{... is wrong.

Comment: the code compiles perfectly now.Please help me for splitting equation.

Comment: It's hard to know where to break the equation without knowing the line width, which depends on the documentclass and/or paper size. Also, I suggest you put some effort into making your LaTeX code readable to *humans* by inserting line breaks and indenting code, keeping more closely related parts together. The code is near impossible to navigate as is.

Comment: Thank you for Your reply, sir. I'm a noob to LaTex and will improve with time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Edition for you,

```
\begin{align}
\int_{\alpha=0}^{\infty}\lambda_1\lambda_2&\exp(-\lambda_1z)\frac{1} {\lambda_1 z+b}\frac{\exp(-\alpha h_{T_x,1}^2)}{p}d\alpha\nonumber\\
=&
\left.-2 b^2 s^2 \log \left(\frac{b \left(a+s^2\right)}{a}\right)-2 a b^2 \log \left(\frac{b \left(a+s^2\right)}{a}\right)+2 b^2 s^2\right.\nonumber\\
&\times \log \left(a+s^2\right)+2 a b^2 \log \left(a+s^2\right)+2 b s^2 e^{\frac{b \left(a+s^2\right)}{a}} \text{Ei}\left(-\frac{b \left(s^2+a\right)}{a}\right)\nonumber\\
&+2 b s^2 e^{\frac{b \left(a+s^2\right)}{a}} \log \left(\frac{b \left(a+s^2\right)}{a}\right)-2 b s^2 \log \left(\frac{b \left(a+s^2\right)}{a}\right)-2 a b \log \left(\frac{b \left(a+s^2\right)}{a}\right)\nonumber\\
&-b s^2 e^{\frac{b \left(a+s^2\right)}{a}} \log \left(-\frac{b \left(a+s^2\right)}{a}\right)-2 (b+1) b \left(a+s^2\right) \log \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)+2 b s^2 \log \left(a+s^2\right)\nonumber\\
&+2 a b \log \left(a+s^2\right)+b s^2 e^{\frac{b \left(a+s^2\right)}{a}} \log \left(-\frac{a}{b \left(a+s^2\right)}\right)+2 a{2 a p},\Re\left(a+s^2\right)>0\nonumber\\
&\land \left(\left(\Re\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)\geq 0
\land \frac{b}{a}\neq 0\right)\lor \frac{b}{a}\notin \mathbb{R}\right)
\end{align}
```

Comment: You should use `&=`, not `=&`, in alignments. That way, spacing comes out right, as the environment is designed. Also, I suggest replacing `&+` with `&\phantom{{}=}+$, and similarly with other lines starting with a binary operation following the ampersand. That puts in an invisible equals sign for you. The `{}` before the equals sign is to make TeX put in the space that ordinarily comes before a relation symbol (the same way `align` does it behind the curtains).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest avoiding the two-story fractions as long as possible, particularly in exponents.

Also, the denominator can be placed at the start and the conditions can be added on a line by themselves.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Ei}{Ei}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2ap}\biggl(
&
-2 b^2 s^2 \log(b(a+s^2)/a)
-2 a b^2 \log(b (a+s^2)/a)
+2 b^2 s^2 \log(a+s^2)
\\
&
+2 a b^2 \log (a+s^2)
+2 b s^2 e^{b(a+s^2)/a} \Ei(-b(s^2+a)/a)
\\
&
+2 b s^2 e^{b(a+s^2)/a} \log(b(a+s^2)/a)
-2 b s^2 \log(b(a+s^2)/a)
\\
&
-2 a b \log(b(a+s^2)/a)
-b s^2 e^{b(a+s^2)/a} \log (-b(a+s^2)/a)
\\
&
-2 (b+1) b(a+s^2) \log(a/b)
+2 b s^2 \log(a+s^2)
+2 a b \log(a+s^2)
\\
&
+b s^2 e^{b(a+s^2)/a} \log\Bigl(-\frac{a}{b(a+s^2)}\Bigr)
+2 a
\biggr)
\\[2ex]
&\Re\left(a+s^2\right)>0 \land 
\left(\left(\Re\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)\geq 0 \land
  \frac{b}{a}\neq 0\right)\lor \frac{b}{a}\notin \mathbb{R}\right)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]